# jQuery Autocomplete onselect redirect (info from database)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I wish to make an autocomplete search input, and when a user selects an item he is redirected to a certain page on the web.
I have a database that contains the Names and Urls. So far I have managed to pick up the Names from the database, and the autocomplete does work. Thing is, I can't figure out how to make the connection between the select event to the specific Url of the name.

I am using asp.net :

my .ASHX file :

```
   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/javascript";
        string cnString = "cnnstringlocation";
        string sql = "SELECT Name FROM [Table] WHERE Name LIKE  '%'+@term+'%' ";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, new SqlConnection(cnString));
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@term", context.Request.QueryString["term"]);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        string[] items = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
        int ctr = 0;


        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            items[ctr] = (string)row["Name"];
            ctr++;
        }

        context.Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(items));


    }
```

And the auto-complete query(this is quite simple, I have made a few tries messing around with the database and change the source so I will have access to the Urls too but without any luck)

```
        $('#tags').autocomplete({
            source: 'Autocomplete.ashx'

        });
```

I am pretty new to jQuery, but I understand that the source should not only contain the string represnting the Names, but also the Urls for each name. I couldn't find the right syntax to do so anywhere.
EDIT: I think I can make another .ASHX file that will fire onselect and then returns the specific URL needed. Is that a right approach? is there a more simple way?
Thanks for any light on that matter.

Answer (score 0):

use the select function and then you can redirect after selecting here is the reference url

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

Comment: I know I need to use the select function, thing is I don't get the Url from the database, only the names that will appear under the autocomplete. how do I combine both the names and urls and handle them correctly in jquery..?

Comment: have you tried this one ? window.location.href = "your url here"; so when you some one select you give the url in that place in your function and it will redirect

Comment: Thanks for the answer,I might not explain myself well. The specific Url for a selected name is stored in the database(column Name, column Url). How do I manage to locate the specific Url of a name chosen on select? I know I need to use the window.location.href eventually but can't figure how to get in touch with the Url.